# PHP database not able to log in

Tags: php, database

I need some assistance with my database, I am not able to log in to it even though it's making a connection to the db.

This is my Connection.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "tools4ever"";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=". $database, $username, 
$password);
```

And this is in my login script:

require "connection.php";
    $rol = $_GET["k"];

```
if (isset($_POST["terug"])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}

if (isset($_POST["registreren"])) {
    if ($rol == "klant") {
        header("Location:registreren.php");
    } else {
        header("Location:medewerkertoevoegen.php");

    }
 }
$persoon = "";
$rol = -1;
$error = 0;
$rol = $_GET["k"];
    if($rol == "medewerker") {
        $gebruikersnaam= $_POST["gebruikersnaam"];
        $wachtwoord = sha1($_POST["wachtwoord"]);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from medewerker where gebruikersnaam=? and wachtwoord=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord));
        $aantalRijen = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($aantalRijen==1) {
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
            $_SESSION["medewerkercode"] = $result["medewerkercode"];
            $tvs = ($result["voorletters"] =="") ? "" : $result["voorletters"]." ";
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $result["voorletters"] ." ". $tvs. " " .$result["achternaam"];
            $_SESSION["medewerkercode"] = $result["medewerkercode"];
             header("Location:overzichtArtikelen.php?k=medewerker");
            $_SESSION["rol"]= "medewerker";
            }
        else {
            $error =-1;
        }


    }
```

And this is how my database currently looks. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc85k.png

Does anyone here know the answer? Much appreciated!

- Tom

Comment: To add to this, I can also provide the whole document of my login script if necessary to check out. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you really mean that you can't log into the database? Or do you mean that when you use the information in the database, you can't log in to the web application you wrote?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: TYPO : $database = "tools4ever"";   typo at the end have two double quotes

Comment: You got a type here: `$database = "tools4ever"";` Twice a double quote at the end...

Comment: After putting in the user/password it doesn't forward to the next page and gives the error of an invalid user/pass even though it's correct.

Comment: Woops.. Removed the double quotes but still doesn't seem to forward me. @JeroenBellemans

Comment: @jyothl Removing the 2 quotes worked, now it gives me an undefined index of gebruikersnaam / wachtwoord on line 33/34                             
 (the one under if($rol == "medewerker") {

Answer (score 1):

`$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);`

try this you are concating the String that PDO doesn't accept.

**EDIT**

For index fix you have to set the name attribute to your form input for both username and password

somthing like this

`<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>`

then you can access them in your login script as

`$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];`

that's it!!!

Comment: Removing the 2 quotes worked, now it gives me an undefined gebruikersnaam / wachtwoord error.

Comment: can't understand upload a snap on imgur...or post the whole error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: gebruikersnaam in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: wachtwoord in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 34

Comment: Undefined index means those indexes haven't been passed through via a $_POST request.

Comment: $gebruikersnaam= $_POST["gebruikersnaam"];
        $wachtwoord = sha1($_POST["wachtwoord"]);  error is here right ?

Comment: Sorry, yes that's where the error is. And I understand that @Mickburkejnr but how can I fix that ^^

Comment: use the form input name attribute like this $_POST['username'] $_POST['password']

Comment: Sorry, how exactly would I have to do that?

Comment: EDITED MY ANSWER.

Comment: So this http://i.imgur.com/ipEIXTi.png @KunalAwasthi ? It now gives 4 errors: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined variable: gebruikersnaam in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined variable: wachtwoord in C:\xampp2\htdocs\inloggen.php on line 36

Comment: `          $gebruikersnaam= $_POST["username"];
           $wachtwoord = sha1($_POST["password"]);`

Comment: have yo changed name attribute of form inputs  ?